# How do I create external (or at least external to the slider) links on the thumbnail navigation?

Tags: jssor

I've been working with the Jssor Slider for the past couple of days and found it to be very good, but I would like to add extra links to the thumbnails when active which will link directly to the page they are highlighting in the slider.

Below you will see I have added a link to the thumbnail, which appears without problem when viewed on a browser, but is not click-able. I believe this is due to it being inside the "thumb" divide which Jssor treats as one object when clicked.

```
<div>
    <img u="image" src="img/slide.jpg" />
    <div u="thumb">
        <img class="i" src="img/thumbnail.jpg"/>
        <div class="t">Service Title</div>
        <div class="c"><a href="link_to_service_page.html">Learn More</a></div>
    </div>
    <div u="caption" t="FADE" class="gradientOverlay"></div>
    <div u="caption" t="L" class="serviceTitle"> Service Title</div>
    <div u="caption" t="B" class="serviceCaption">Brief Summary of Service.</div>
    <div u="caption" t="R" class="serviceMore"><a href="service_page.html">Learn More</a></div>
</div>
```

I have also tried to add the link as a caption on the slide, but it appears behind the navigation thumbnails, and z-indexing doesn't seem to work, I'm guessing because the javascript overrides it.

Lastly I tried using 'u="any"' on the link but again that doesn't work, although this seems to be the best route to follow, by marking the link as data, the Jssor script should be able to identify it and execute an action. But this is where I begin to get lost as I'm still learning javascript, hence why I'm using Jssor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your "Learn More" text appearing on screen even if it's not clickable? Have you tried putting your href as a part of the <div u="thumb"> attributes, and changing your div class=c to <div class="c">Learn More</div>?

Comment: Yes "Learn More" is visible and the link even opens if I right click on it and select 'open in new tab' for example. But when I left click on it, the script takes over and navigates to the associated slide. Putting the href on the whole div does navigate to the page I want it to, but then it no longer navigates to the associated slide. I have played around with it using hover instead of click, which works OK. I would just rather have it so you click on thumbnail > Slide + "Learn More" appear, then click on "Learn More" > Navigate to Full Page.

Comment: I have just tested it, it works. Not sure what's going wrong. Maybe  you need to download the latest version.